# How do you create a php file editor in php

Tags: php, text-editor

I am trying to create a php file that can edit other php files on my website. I am able to do this except for when there is html in the php file that I want to edit. Since I am using a textarea to display/edit the php file contents, what I have built does not work when there is a textarea tag in the php file that I want to edit. What I have so far is below. The solution does not need to resemble this.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['file_text']){
file_put_contents($_POST['filename'], $_POST['file_text']);

$filename = $_POST['filename'];
echo "<script>
window.location = '_editor.php?filenm=$filename'
</script>";

}

else {

$myfilename = $_GET['filenm'];
if(file_exists($myfilename)){
$file_text= file_get_contents($myfilename);
}

echo "

<h3>$myfilename</h3>

<form name='input' action='_editor.php?filenm=$myfilename' method='post'>

<textarea name='contrib_entrybox' id='contrib_entrybox' rows='50' cols='180'>
$file_text
</textarea>";

?>
```

Comment: Use html entities and convert them back when you're done. SIDE NOTE - be VERY VERY CAREFUL to allow only authorized users to edit your content, and only content they are supposed to be editing.

Comment: and be ready to write a ton of sanitizing code. think of all the things you can do with exec()

Comment: Why is this something you feel you need to do? What are you hoping to gain by doing this?  You want to spend a bunch of time building a PHP editor (and it would be a bunch of time if you want it to be secure and anywhere nearly as functional as a typical IDE or even notepad), just so you don't have to deploy files to the server?

Comment: Currently, I can make changes in pretty much the same way using an editor that my web host provides. Unfortunately, I am not always able to access the web host's site.

Comment: @user3573827 Then get a new hosting company. Or better yet, get yourself a better deployment process.  If you continue down the path of learning web development/programming you need to get away from editing files in place on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // configuration
    $url = 'http://domain.com/backend/editor.php';
    $yourfilePath = '/path/to/txt/file';

    // check if form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['text'])){
        // save the text contents
        file_put_contents($yourfilePath, $_POST['text']);

        // redirect to form again
        header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
        printf('<a href="%s">Moved</a>.', htmlspecialchars($url));
        exit();
    }

    // read the textfile
    $text = file_get_contents($yourfilePath);

?>
<!-- HTML form -->
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div id="sample">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
 
  </script>

  <h4>
    Second Textarea
  </h4>
  <textarea name="area2" style="width: 100%;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea><br />
            
</div>
```

Comment: you can put only this code in your php file and the text editor is display in your page and also upload the images